# organizing your classes based on the database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, database, class

So every website I make in ASP.NET, for every table I have in the database I'm creating a class that will make my life easier when dealing with database data while using SQL INJECTION safe ways.

In each class for each table, I do those methods to make my life easier:

- Each column in the database I create a var to it.
- Constructor that gets data to the object by ID from the database.
- getters and setters.
- UpdateDb() that being called when using a setter on a existing object
- Add method to add an account based on the object to database
- Delete method to remove an existing object from database

On this new website I'm building I have like 14 tables, and making to each one of the tables a class is exhausting and annoying. Is there a BETTER way or alternative to arrange classes in ASP.NET that someone can suggest? What you guys are doing in your website to arrange the Database data? Maybe I'll learn a new way. Thanks.

Here is an example for "Accounts" table class:

```
public class Accounts : SqlMain
{

    //Declare all vars based on the Database column name
    private int id;
    private string username;
    private string password;
    private string email;
    private string first_name;
    private string last_name;
    private int subscription_days;
    private int admin;
    private bool ghosted;
    private int warnings;
    private bool banned;
    private DateTime registration_date;
    private bool trial;

    //Get all the data of row with specific id, if it doesn't exists its will be an empty object (account)
    public Accounts(int id)
    {
        Connection con = new Connection();
        con.conOpen();
        MySqlCommand msc = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE id = @id");
        msc.Connection = con.Con;
        msc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        MySqlDataReader r = msc.ExecuteReader();
        if (r.Read())
        {
            this.id = r.GetInt32(0);
            this.username = r.GetString(1);
            this.password = r.GetString(2);
            this.email = r.GetString(3);
            this.first_name = r.GetString(4);
            this.last_name = r.GetString(5);
            this.subscription_days = r.GetInt32(6);
            this.admin = r.GetInt32(7);
            this.ghosted = r.GetBoolean(8);
            this.warnings = r.GetInt32(9);
            this.banned = r.GetBoolean(10);
            this.registration_date = r.GetDateTime(11);
            this.trial = r.GetBoolean(12);
        }
    }

    //get all user data
    public Accounts(String username, String password)
    {
        Connection con = new Connection();
        con.conOpen();
        MySqlCommand msc = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `username` = @username AND `password` = @password");
        msc.Connection = con.Con;
        msc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
        msc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
        MySqlDataReader r = msc.ExecuteReader();
        if (r.Read())
        {
            this.id = r.GetInt32(0);
            this.username = r.GetString(1);
            this.password = r.GetString(2);
            this.email = r.GetString(3);
            this.first_name = r.GetString(4);
            this.last_name = r.GetString(5);
            this.subscription_days = r.GetInt32(6);
            this.admin = r.GetInt32(7);
            this.ghosted = r.GetBoolean(8);
            this.warnings = r.GetInt32(9);
            this.banned = r.GetBoolean(10);
            this.registration_date = r.GetDateTime(11);
            this.trial = r.GetBoolean(12);
        }
    }

    //get and set
    public int Id { get => id; set { id = value; } }
    public string Username { get => username; set { username = value; UpdateDb(); } }
    public string Password { get => password; set { password = value; UpdateDb(); } }
    public string Email { get => email; set { email = value; UpdateDb(); } }
    public string First_name { get => first_name; set { first_name = value; UpdateDb(); } }
    public string Last_name { get => last_name; set { last_name = value; UpdateDb(); } }
    public int Subscription_days { get => subscription_days; set { subscription_days = value; UpdateDb(); } }
    public int Admin { get => admin; set { admin = value; UpdateDb(); } }
    public bool Ghosted { get => ghosted; set { ghosted = value; UpdateDb(); } }
    public int Warnings { get => warnings; set { warnings = value; UpdateDb(); } }
    public bool Banned { get => banned; set { banned = value; UpdateDb(); } }
    public DateTime Registration_date { get => registration_date; set { registration_date = value; UpdateDb(); } }
    public bool Trial { get => trial; set { trial = value; UpdateDb(); } }

    //Updates DB
    public void UpdateDb()
    {
        Connection con = new Connection();
        con.conOpen();
        MySqlCommand msc = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE id = @id");
        msc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Id);
        msc.Connection = con.Con;
        MySqlDataReader r = msc.ExecuteReader();
        if (r.Read())
        {
            r.Close();
            MySqlCommand cm = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE `accounts` SET `username` = @username, `password` = @password, `email` = @email, `first_name` = @first_name, last_name = @last_name, subscription_days = @subscription_days, admin = @admin, `ghosted` = @ghosted, `warnings` = @warnings, `banned` = @banned, `registration_date` = @registration_date, `trial` = @trial WHERE `id` = @id");
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Username);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Password);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Email);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_name", First_name);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_name", Last_name);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subscription_days", Subscription_days);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admin", Admin);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ghosted", Ghosted);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@warnings", Warnings);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@banned", Banned);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@registration_date", Registration_date);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trial", Trial);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Id);
            cm.Connection = con.Con;
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        con.conClose();
    }

    //Adds new row in accounts based on the object
    public void AddAccount()
    {
        Connection con = new Connection();
        con.conOpen();
        MySqlCommand msc = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE id = @id");
        msc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Id);
        msc.Connection = con.Con;
        MySqlDataReader r = msc.ExecuteReader();
        if (!r.Read())
        {
            r.Close();
            MySqlCommand cm = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `accounts` (username, password, email, first_name, last_name, subscription_days, admin, ghosted, warnings, banned, registration_date, tiral) VALUES (@username, @password, @email, @first_name, @last_name, @subscription_days, @admin, @ghosted, @warnings, @banned, @registration_date, @tiral)");
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Username);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Password);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Email);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_name", First_name);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_name", Last_name);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subscription_days", Subscription_days);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admin", Admin);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ghosted", Ghosted);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@warnings", Warnings);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@banned", Banned);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@registration_date", Registration_date);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trial", Trial);
            cm.Connection = con.Con;
            cm.Prepare();
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        con.conClose();
    }

    //Delete this object from sql
    public void DeleteAccount()
    {
        Connection con = new Connection();
        con.conOpen();
        MySqlCommand msc = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE id = @id");
        msc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Id);
        MySqlDataReader r = msc.ExecuteReader();
        if (r.Read())
        {
            r.Close();
            MySqlCommand cm = new MySqlCommand("DELETE FROM `accounts` WHERE id = @id");
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Id);
            cm.Prepare();
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        con.conClose();
    }
}
```

Comment: use `EntityFramework` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/

Comment: EntityFramework is a great way to manipulate your SQL database. I suggest you to dig into it, very easy once you get grasp of it. What you doing now is frustrating and is waste of time. There is easier alternatives! Good luck :)

Comment: Oooooo thank you very much! Didn’t know it existed.